# ImageMagick creating bad gif animation

Tags: c++, file, imagemagick, gif

When I try to create a gif using ICO ImageMagic, it overlays frames on top of each other

```
std::vector<Magick::Image> frames;
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                    Magick::Image img((temp+"/icons"+QString::number(i)+".ico").toStdString().c_str());
                    frames.push_back(img);
                    frames[i].animationDelay(100);
                }
Magick::writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), ("/icons/"+list->at(x)+".gif").toStdString());
```

I tried to change .ico format to .cur but nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if somebody has this problem use this:

```
Magick::DisposeType disposeMethod = Magick::DisposeType::BackgroundDispose;
```

...

for all frames

```
frame[i].gifDisposeMethod(disposeMethod);
```